# Webforms - modify certian components to export into one column, in Excel format

Tags: webforms

I am using webforms and downloading the submissions with an Excel format.

I have four check-boxes at the end of the webform asking the user if they agree on the terms and conditions of the form.

When I download the submissions those four check-boxes are outputted, but the client only need to know if the submission is `True` for all those fields.

this is whats being displayed now:

```
SID |  col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
--------------------------------
 1     T      F      T      F
 2     T      T      T      T
```

I am looking for this type of download:

```
SID |  agreeCol 
---------------
 1       F    
 2       T
```

The logic and rewriting I can handle but I am just curious if there is a way of achieving this with webforms out of the box? and if not, what are my options?

Comment: you could do this with hook_webform_csv_data_alter()--
http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_csv_data_alter/7

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. I hate that there is literally no documentation on these hooks.
Unfortunately I can't use devel's `dpm()` anywhere inside that hook to see what data i need to use. In order to determine the CID's I had to use dpm inside `hook_webform_component_display_alter`. making progress now :D